# What's the use of "<> 0" in expression?

Tags: vb6

I'm very well understand the use of "<>" operator in IF statements but when it's used in expression like "foo = checkbox.value <> 0" then what does it do to "foo" variable?

Comment: The result of the an inequality test involving `<>` is either `true` or `false` so `foo` is a assigned `true` or `false` depending on the result of `checkbox.value <> 0`.

Comment: It's another (and maybe less obvious) way of writing `foo = CBool(checkbox.value)`

Comment: Note that the VB Checkbox has three states: vbUnchecked ( = 0 ), vbChecked ( = 1), vbGrayed ( = 2). In this case, foo is True if the checkbox Value property is vbChecked or vbGrayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` will be assigned a boolean value.

The right hand side will result in either `True` or `False`.